# Workgroup Bound Check not working

Tags: opencl

In my OpenCL kernel i'm checking if the global_id is inside the global problem size but it is not working.

If the global problem size is dividable by the workgroupsize everything is fine. If not, the kernel is doing just nothing.

```
__kernel void move_points(const unsigned int points,
                              const unsigned int floors,
                              const unsigned int gridWidth,
                              const unsigned int gridHeight,
                              __global const GraphData *graph,
                              __global const float *pin_x,
                              __global const float *pin_y,
                              __global const float *pin_z,
                              __global float *pout_x,
                              __global float *pout_y,
                              __global float *pout_z,
                              __global clrngMrg31k3pHostStream *streams)
{
    int id = get_global_id(0);

    if (id < points) {
        do kernel things...
    }
}
```

Do somebody know where the problem is?

Thanks a lot. Robin.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If your global size is not divisible by your local size (workgroup size), then the kernel will not run at all.

The `enqueueNDRangeKernel()` call will return CL_INVALID_WORK_GROUP_SIZE as an error as specified [here](https://www.khronos.org/registry/cl/sdk/1.0/docs/man/xhtml/clEnqueueNDRangeKernel.html).

---

If you really want to follow the CUDA mode, where you may have unused work items. Then put the check in the kernel (as you already have), and use a bigger global size, that is multiple of your local size.

Comment: Okay thanks very much. According to this, if i'm able two vary my global problem size, it is the best to calculate the my global work items as a multiple of the maximum workgroupsize of the device right?

for example my max workgroupsize is 1024 then i set my global problem size to 1024 * 1000?

Comment: In the general case, if you can, then YES. Bigger work group size is better to get higher device utilization. But not always, sometimes is better to have a smaller size to be able to store more memory per work-item. Or maybe your local problem size is easier to solve with another group size.